# Create Template to add text to document

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, macros

I have one template which have macros. Macros will add some text to document when document will open.

when I attched this template to any document, macros of the template also work for that document.
it add some text to that document which have this attched template.

But I want to do this using visual studio 2010 using C# code.
I dont know how to do this.
can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you talking about a Word template? And what is it you're trying to accomplish with C#? Do you want to recreate the fucntion of the macro? Or you want C# to automatically attach the template to any document?

Comment: is there any alternative of macro in Visual Studio 210

Comment: Have you read Microsoft's documentation? It explains how to create and use macros in Visual Studio 2010.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution about this issue. I have developed the VSTO document level Addins. And its working as I want... After developing VSTO document level Addins just need to Add _AssemblyLocation and _AssemblyName to the document.